# Is there a VisualCron open source equivalent for Debian based distros?

Tags: cron, gui

I'm sometimes using this Swiss Army Knife tool called [VisualCron](https://www.visualcron.com/) when I'm working on Windows for managing many... many tasks, from database backup/restore, to launching remote scripts, and so on.

I was wondering, is there an open source equivalent with a nice GUI for Debian based distributions (Ubuntu)?

Comment: You will get better help if you detail the features you seek. Example workflow would also be helpful. Most folks here will be unfamiliar with that Windows product, so they won't know what you seek.

Comment: https://ostechnix.com/zeit-a-gui-front-end-to-crontab-to-schedule-jobs-in-linux/  like that?

Comment: I think `emacs` has a "nice GUi" and use it to manage my `crontab`s, but I wouldn't recommend it. Please [edit] your question and describe the features you're looking for. I'm unfamiliar with VisualCron.